# Disk Space full while doing apt-get operation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, partitioning, purge

Im Trying to install new software on my Ubuntu 14.04, which is running

```
    uname -r
3.13.0-45-generic
```

There are old kernals installed on my machine

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic       3.13.0-24.47                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic       3.13.0-45.74                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic       3.13.0-55.94                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic       3.13.0-57.95                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic       3.13.0-58.97                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic       3.13.0-59.98                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic       3.13.0-61.100                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic 3.13.0-24.47                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic 3.13.0-45.74                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic 3.13.0-55.94                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic 3.13.0-57.95                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic 3.13.0-58.97                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic 3.13.0-59.98                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic 3.13.0-61.100                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic 3.13.0-62.102                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic                 3.13.0.62.69                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

When i am trying to Purge them using below command

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Im getting above error.

While doing auto remove getting error

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

and if i run force install it is saying no space left on device ..

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-55 linux-headers-3.13.0-55-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-57 linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-58 linux-headers-3.13.0-58-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-59 linux-headers-3.13.0-59-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.13.0 linux-source-3.13.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 48 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 15.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 42.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirrors.voxel.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic amd64 3.13.0-62.102 [15.2 MB]
Fetched 15.2 MB in 4s (3,237 kB/s)                        
(Reading database ... 243451 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic_3.13.0-62.102_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic (3.13.0-62.102) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic_3.13.0-62.102_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-62-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-62-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic_3.13.0-62.102_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can i make space on my Ubuntu so that i can install new applications on it ?

Please help...

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove some old kernel images (and corresponding `linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic`) with `dpkg` directly:

```
dpkg -r linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
```

IIRC this should work. If it is still complaining about dependencies and you are sure about the version you are uninstalling, add `--force-depends`

Answer (score 0):

I found a lot in `/var/cache`.

(After an unsuccessful attempt to install java 8 from ppa)

BTW, I moved the folder `/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer` to `/media/flash_ext3/var/cache` (where *`flash_ext3`* is the name of a 32G USB stick formatted to use ext3) and created a link:

```
cd /var/cache
sudo ln -s /media/flash_ext3/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer oracle-jdk8-installer
```

(and did a `chmod a+rwx`)